# How to move player object in 2d array using struct

Tags: c++

I'm making a maze game that uses a player structure and takes user input. The program runs, but nothing changes when I input commands to move my player. Any advice on whats going wrong?

```
// The function for user input
void getMove()
{

Player player1;

cout << "\n\nWhich direction would you like to go? ----- Treasure: " << numTreasure << "\n\n";
cout << "Up: 8\n";
cout << "Down: 2\n";
cout << "Left: 4\n";
cout << "Right: 6\n";

cin >> direction;


switch(direction)
{
    case 8 :
        if (currentBoard[player1.playerX - 1][player1.playerY] != '#'){
        player1.playerX--;
        }
        break;

    case 2 :
        if (currentBoard[player1.playerX + 1][player1.playerY] != '#'){
        player1.playerX++;
        break;
        }

    case 4 :
        if (currentBoard[player1.playerX][player1.playerY - 1] != '#'){
        player1.playerY--;
        break;
        }

    case 6 :
        if (currentBoard[player1.playerX][player1.playerY + 1] != '#'){
        player1.playerY++;
        break;
        }
}

switch(currentBoard[player1.playerX][player1.playerY]){
    case '*':
    cout << "You picked up a gold nugget!" << endl;
    board[player1.playerX][player1.playerY] = treasureSpace;
    numTreasure++;
    break;


  }
}
```

`

Comment: `"nothing changes"` is not a descriptive problem and we will need more information if you want us to be able to help you. Also, have you set any break points and walked through your code?

Comment: Sorry. What I mean by nothing changes is that when I type any number to move in my maze the maze is redrawn and my player movement is not updated in the array.

Comment: As we have no code to look at which covers "redrawing your maze" we don't have enough info and you still didn't answer whether you set breakpoints and stepped through your code.

Comment: I did not use breakpoints and step trough the code. Would it help to see the entire project?

Comment: If you really think having the whole solution is going to be able to help us help you, then by all means place it in a public repo on GIT or some other public repo, else just add more to your post to show the code where you redraw the maze and when does it execute compared with the above example, also, if you a re going to begin a career or try to make a living in programming, `debugging` is an essential skill, learning to set break points and step through code is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `direction` variable that is read in with `cin >>` is of type `char*`.  In your switch-case you are comparing this `direction` variable against integers, so you will never get any of these cases AND you do not have a default case.  I would switch the `direction` that is brought in from the user to an `int` with a type cast

```
`int_direction = (int)direction`
```

and then change your switch cases to compare against `int_direction`